# Angular 11 print component inside another component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a simple component where I've placed multiple buttons and I want to show those buttons in another component (functionality of buttons also comes from my buttons component) but i get this error in terminal

```
ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(HelpdeskModule)[ButtonsComponent -> ButtonsComponent -> ButtonsComponent -> ButtonsComponent]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for ButtonsComponent!
```

## Code

`buttons.component.html`

```
<div class="mb-3">
  <nz-button-group>
      <button nz-button nzType="primary" (click)="buttonClick('create button')" class="ant-btn ant-btn-primary ant-btn-lg"><i nz-icon nzType="download"></i>Create New</button>
  </nz-button-group>
</div>
```

`list.component.ts` (this is where i want to show those components)

```
  import { ButtonsComponent } from 'src/app/components/app/layout/buttons/buttons.component';

  constructor(
    private buttons: ButtonsComponent,
  ) { }
```

And `list.component.html`

```
// I am uncertain about this part to be correct at all!
{{buttons}}
```

**Any idea?**

## Update

I've added `Injectable` to my buttons component like this: (just playing around to get them printed )

```
import { Component, OnInit, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { NzNotificationService } from 'ng-zorro-antd'


@Component({
  selector: 'app-buttons',
  templateUrl: './buttons.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./buttons.component.scss']
})

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ButtonsComponent implements OnInit {
  //
}
```

and now I'm getting this error

```
ERROR TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance.
In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method.
```

Answer (score 2):

First thing, inside `list.component.html` just place html like below

`<app-buttons></app-buttons>`

And then you want to call method of of `ButtonsComponent`, use it as a dependency, you have to keep it in providers array first.

```
providers: [
  ...,
  ButtonsComponent,
  ...
]
```

---

But as I look through your updated question, you don't have to inject the component inside constructor, rather you can use `ViewChild`.

```
@ViewChild('buttons', { static: false, read: ViewContainerRef })
buttons: ButtonsComponent;
```

**list.component.html**

```
<app-buttons #buttons></app-buttons>
```

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-zorro-antd-ivy-vbacs8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Hi, where should I place this `viewChild`? in my buttons component or list component? and `ViewContainerRef` if imported from?

Comment: @mafortis I'm little unsure now after your question update. What exactly you want to do. Just you to render the `app-buttons` component inside `list.component.html` and call its method from parent component?

Comment: Yes I want to print them in my `list.component.html` and no, for now there will be nothing dynamically passed from `list.component.html` to `buttons.component.ts` it all static now

Comment: it returns `ERROR TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance.
In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method.`

Comment: You have to remove `private buttons: ButtonsComponent,` from constructor and `{{buttons}}` from html, and then use what I've suggestted

Comment: you're right, the error is gone but still no button printed in my view

Comment: hey, no idea..?

Comment: @mafortis what do you mean by *no button printed?*

Comment: I mean I cannot see my buttons in `list.component.html`

Comment: sorry i didn't know that you've updated your answer :/ first thing tomorrow morning I will test your update and let you know.

Comment: @mafortis please check stackblitz added in the answer

Answer (score 0):

Using ComponentFactoryResolver in Angular to handle dynamic loader for multiple components:

Here is sample code:

```
import {
    Component,
    ComponentFactory,
    ComponentRef,
    ComponentFactoryResolver,
    ViewContainerRef,
    ViewChild
} from '@angular/core'
import { AComponent } from './a.component';
import { BComponent } from './b.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'modal-resolver',
    template: `
        <template #modalContainer></template>
    `,
})
export class ModalResolver {
    @ViewChild("modalContainer", { read: ViewContainerRef }) container;
    @Input() name;
    componentRef: ComponentRef;

    listComponent: {
        'modalA': AComponent,
        'modalB': BComponent
    }

    constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.loadComponent(this.name);
    }
    loadComponent(type) {
        this.container.clear();
        const factory: ComponentFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.listComponent[this.name]);

        this.componentRef = this.container.createComponent(factory);

        this.componentRef.instance.type = type;

        this.componentRef.instance.output.subscribe(event => console.log(event));

    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.componentRef.destroy();
    }
}
```

Then you use it:

```
<modal-resolver name="modalA"></modal-resolver>
```

Comment: Not sure, when OP asked to load component dynamically?

Comment: `ERROR TypeError: this.listComponent is undefined`

Answer (score 0):

```js
  printComponent(elementId: any, scape: any = 'landscape') {
    const originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
    const printContents = document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML;
    const css = '@page { size: ' + scape + '; }';
    const head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    const style: any = document.createElement('style');

    style.type = 'text/css';
    style.media = 'print';

    if (style.styleSheet) {
      style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
    } else {
      style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
    }

    head.appendChild(style);

    document.body.innerHTML = printContents;

    window.print();

    document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;

    window.location.reload();
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <h3>Page d'impression des états</h3>
  <button
    nbButton size="tiny" outline status="warning" class="align-middle"
    (click)="printComponent('componentId')"
  >
    <nb-icon icon="print-outline"></nb-icon>
    IMPRIMER
  </button>
  <div id="usersId">
    <table class="table" id="componentId">
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Class</th>
        <th scope="col">Heading</th>
        <th scope="col">Heading</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let i of [].constructor(100)">
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">Default</th>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="table-primary">
          <th scope="row">Primary</th>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table-secondary">
          <th scope="row">Secondary</th>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table-success">
          <th scope="row">Success</th>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table-danger">
          <th scope="row">Danger</th>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table-warning">
          <th scope="row">Warning</th>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table-info">
          <th scope="row">Info</th>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table-light">
          <th scope="row">Light</th>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table-dark">
          <th scope="row">Dark</th>
          <td>Cell</td>
          <td>Cell</td>
        </tr>
      </ng-container>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Any explanation to back this code up please?